# Drawer Icons Placement

Tags: react-native

***What I wanted to do:***

- Drawer's Icon and Drawer's label is close to each other with a margin of 7
- Put settings and logout at the bottom of the drawer

***Image of Current Drawer:***

[image: Current Drawer]

***What I already tried:***

1. I styled my labelStyle in my DrawerItems Tried marginRight, marginLeft, paddingRight, paddingLeft but It doesn't seem to move close to the Icon.
2. I styled my drawerIcon inside the navigationOptions of my drawerNavigator. Tried marginRight, marginLeft, paddingRight, paddingLeft but It doesn't seem to move close to the Icon.

   ( as for putting the drawer label below, I have no idea how to do that )

**My code for my customDrawerComponent is this:**

```
const CustomDrawerComponent = (props)=>(
  <SafeAreaView>
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', height:150, backgroundColor: 
     Colors.white, alignItems:'center', alignSelf: 'flex-start', marginLeft: 
 15,}}>
    <Image source={Images.trump} style={{height:80, width:80, 
    borderRadius:80/2}} />
    <View>
      <Text style={{marginLeft: 10,marginBottom: 5, fontSize: 16,  
             fontFamily: 'CoreSansD55Bold', color: Colors.gray,}}>      Donald 
    </Text>
      <Text style={{marginLeft: 12, fontSize: 9, color: Colors.heavyGray, 
     fontFamily: 'CoreSansD35Regular', }}> Graphic Designer </Text> 
    </View>
        
</View>
<ScrollView>
  <DrawerItems {...props}  
  activeTintColor= {Colors.white} 
  activeBackgroundColor={Colors.white} 
  inactiveTintColor={Colors.white} 
  inactiveBackgroundColor='transparent' 
  labelStyle={{ color: Colors.heavyGray , fontFamily: 'CoreSansD35Regular', 
fontWeight: 'normal', fontSize: 15,  }}
  />
</ScrollView>
```

**My navigationOptions code:**

```
JobFeed: {
screen: DashboardStack,
navigationOptions: {
  drawerLabel: 'Job Feed',
  drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed',
  drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
  <Icon4 name = "briefcase" size = {15} color = {Colors.heavyGray}/>  )  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the createBottomTabNavigator in ReactNativation.  This example creates a register and login tab at the bottom.

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const Login = createBottomTabNavigator({
   Login: LoginTab,
   Register: RegisterTab
 }, {
tabBarOptions: {
    activeBackgroundColor: '#9575CD',
    inactiveBackgroundColor: '#D1C4E9',
    activeTintColor: '#ffffff',
    inactiveTintColor: 'gray'
 }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help, Charles. I really appreciate it unfortunately I need the settings and logout inside of the drawer and I have to place it in the bottom of the drawer navigation not in the screen.

Comment: With a stack navigator I don't know how you're going to specifically put something down at the bottom.  Look at these examples for react bottom navigation.  https://aboutreact.com/react-native-bottom-navigation/

Comment: Oh you've got it all wrong, I want it inside the drawer not the stack. Just to clarify, I want the settings and logout on the bottom part of the drawer navigation as you can see settings and logout is in the line of the drawerItems, now I want it seperated inside the drawer but in the most bottom side part of the drawer: )